# Cómo encriptar un campo de SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Estoy encriptando un campo que es `password` para ello mi tabla se llama `usuario` que tiene estos campos:

- `idlogin`
- `username`
- `llave`
- `Nombres`
- `dni`

Para encryptar estoy usando este procedimiento al momento de insertar un registro:

```
create PROCEDURE RegistrarUsuario
@username nvarchar(50),
@llave nvarchar(50),
@nombres nvarchar(500),
@dni nvarchar(8)
AS
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.usuario
            (username,llave,Nombres,dni)
    VALUES  (@username 
             , ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('password', @llave)  
             ,@nombres 
             ,@dni  
             )
 end
GO
```

Pero al momento de registrar en el campo llave que está encriptado sale en blanco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacer eso? No deberías cifrar la contraseña a no ser que tengas una muy buena razón para ello. Lo que deberías hacer es generar un hash salteado. Preferiblemente a nivel de aplicación, no en la base de datos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De inicio, el campo `Llave` debe estar declarado de tipo `VARBINARY`, esto para que ahí se guarde el valor encriptado. Para esto la definición de la tabla deberá quedar de la siguiente forma (o por lo menos algo parecido):

```
CREATE Table Usuario (
    LoginId INT Identity (1,1),
    UserName VARCHAR(50),
    Llave VARBINARY(8000),
    Nombres VARCHAR(50),
    DNI VARCHAR(8)
)
```

Seguido, el guardado para el campo `Llave` deberá ser con:

```
ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Clave de encriptado', 'Aqui va la contraseña del usuario')
```

Para que el INSERT quede de la siguiente forma:

```
INSERT INTO Usuario (
    UserName
    ,Llave
    ,Nombres
    ,DNI
    )
VALUES (
    'PFLORES'
    ,ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('password', 'ContrasenaUsuario')
    ,'Flores Espinoza Pierro Joshep'
    ,'71697274'
)
```

Ahora, para recuperar la contraseña encriptada, será con:

```
DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Clave de desencriptado', 'Campo para recuperar contraseña'))
```

Para que tu `SELECT` quede de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT 
     LoginId
    ,UserName
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('password', Llave))
    ,Nombres
    ,DNI
FROM Usuario
```

Aquí podrás ver la <kbd>[demostración](http://rextester.com/LRCTF73329)</kbd>

Finalmente, tu *Stored Procedure* debe quedar de la siguiente forma, nota que el tipo de dato del parámetro `@llave` es un `VARCHAR` y no un `NVARCHAR`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RegistrarUsuario @username VARCHAR(50)
    ,@llave VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@nombres VARCHAR(500)
    ,@dni VARCHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Usuario (
        UserName
        ,Llave
        ,Nombres
        ,DNI
        )
    VALUES (
        @username
        ,ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('password', @llave)
        ,@nombres
        ,@dni
        )
END
```

Aquí podrás ver la segunda <kbd>[demostración](http://rextester.com/PBG1916)</kbd>

Nota: no estoy seguro si los términos *encriptado* y *desencriptado* existan pero espero que con eso se pueda entender mejor la respuesta.

Comment: y en un procedimiento como seria ya que me sale error

Comment: En el procedimiento intentas hacer el insert o el select?

Comment: insert into 
como mi pregunta que realice con ese query.

Comment: No veo nungún tema al querer utilizar el mismo stored peocedure, qué error te tira?

Comment: Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure RegistrarUsuario, Line 0
Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: Realicé la prueba y no me tira ningún error, de cualquier forma edité mi respuesta poniendo el código del *stored procedure*

Comment: Muchas Gracias te agradesco @Flxtr

Answer (score 0):

Important n' before text (nvarchar is diferente to nchar)

and do the  cast to nvarchar

sample:

```
 Declare @cf Nvarchar(200);
set @cf = N'Esta es la clave de cifrado';

    DECLARE @N varbinary(8000)
    SELECT @N= ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@cf,  N'ESTO ES ES UN EJEMPLO')
     SELECT @N
 SELECT CAST( DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@cf,@N) AS NVARCHAR(100))
```

Comment: Podrias decirlo en español, me confundiste T_T

Answer (score -1):

Una de las soluciones mas comunes es usar un `salt` adicional para cada entrada.

Ejemplo en PHP, pero el concepto aplica:

Al crear el registro generar un salt y un hash concatenando la contraseña con el salt.

```
$password = "Hello World";
$salt = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
$saltedPassword = hash('sha256', $password.$salt);
```

Almacenar en la base de datos `$salt` y `$saltedPassword`.

Al momento de verificar si la clave es válida utilizas la misma concatenación con el salt pero esta vez con la clave a verificar y la comparas con `$saltedPassword`:

```
$loginSuccess = $saltedPassword == hash('sha256', $incomingPassword.$salt);
```

De esta manera eres menos vulnerable a que rompan las contraseñas en masa con un ataque de diccionario de hashes.

Comment: Me parece que el OP no indica si utiliza PHP, indica que se debe realizar directamente en el manejador de base de datos, en este caso, SQL Server.